# Repeat on iOS 8.4 music app?

Tags: ios, music.app

Where is the repeat button on a song for iOS 8.4 music app? Help!

Answer (score 5):

When playing a song, tap on the Miniplayer (the bar above the Music app button selections, it shows your song title and artist, etc., it changes per song) to bring up the full song player. Once you are in the full song view, you will have access to the shuffle and repeat buttons.

[image: player with shuffle and repeat buttons]