# How can I repeat a Playlist?

Tags: ios, music

I have an iPhone 5, iOS 8.4.1. How can I repeat a Playlist? I've found how to repeat a song, but I want to repeat a playlist.

Comment: Smoosher already answered this question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195071/repeat-on-ios-8-4-music-app

Comment: Please do not answer your own question by editing it; you can add an answer if you wish, clicking on the button below the existing ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Select your playlist.
Tap on or drag the mini player up to display the full player.

[image: mini player]

Then tap the repeat icon.

[image: full player, repeat activated]

If tapped twice, it will repeat the song currently played only (a tiny "1" appears on the top right side of the icon).